# CKEditor 5: icons not visible

Tags: laravel, webpack, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm just trying new CKEditor 5 and after compiling the code with [laravel-mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix), which uses webpack, the icons are extracted to the public directory under `fonts` directory, but when I load the editor - they are not showing.

Is there any webpack configuration I could use to specify where I want them to be saved and I'm not quite clear on how to fix the issue with icons not showing.

Comment: This question is more about Webpack and Laravel. CKEditor 5 simply imports its icons (SVGs). To make it work, it needs to have those SVGs handled by Webpack and this can be done using `raw-loader` just like explained in https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html#lets-start. If you need compatibility with Laravel's configuration, then you need to see how you can adjust Laravel's config.

Comment: Besides, it would help if you were more specific because right now to help you people would need to recreate the problem and this involves getting into two unrelated projects (Laravel and CKEditor 5) which significantly reduces the number of developers who might know the answer straight away.